# What may be the difference in the usage of 自尊心, 誇り and 自慢?

Tags: usage, words, nuances, meaning, word-choice

I read a paragraph and it contains the word `自尊心`.
I want to know the meaning of `自尊心`.
Dictionary says `自尊心 = pride`.
Is it the same with `誇り`? or `自慢`?

What may be the differences in the usage of these words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- 誇り is a kind of pride concerned with your characteristics like: membership to some group (i.e., nationality, alumnus status, etc.),  your belief, activity, or achievement.

> 誇りを持って仕事をしている
>   日本人であることに誇りを感じている

- 自尊心 is the pride about being yourself, and is not tied to any of the particular characteristics mentioned above.

> 自尊心を持つことは、よい人格形成にとって必要だ
>   犬の自尊心を育てるためには、小さいときに他の犬と一緒に過ごさせることが重要だ

- 自慢 is the act of showing off something related to yourself, like the characteristics mentioned above, or your belongings.

> スネ夫がラジコン飛行機を自慢した
>   出木杉君は、試験の結果がよくても、決して自慢はしない

Comment: それなら,"I will not do anything under my friends' leading" は"自尊心"ですか?

Comment: I think it can be.